# Output to DataGridView is showing the amount of characters and not the string names

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

The `DataGridView` is displaying the number of characters in each string and not the names.

When I run the query in MySql workbench I get the correct output so I think the issue is where I am adding the query to the typesByMonth list.

I am getting the following output from the code provided:

`Length 3 14`

```
    private void TypesByMonthRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        List<String> typesByMonth = new List<String>();


        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["U04i5a"].ConnectionString;

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(CS))
        {
            con.Open();
            //string query = "SELECT DISTINCT type, COUNT(type) FROM appointment WHERE (start > @start && end < @end) GROUP BY type;";
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT type FROM appointment;";

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                        {
                            typesByMonth.Add(reader["type"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ReportsDataGridView.DataSource = typesByMonth;

    }
```

The following is the output needed and what is given from the query in when tested in the workbench. "type" is the column.

`Type xyz`

General Doctor

Comment: This behaviour seems to be correct. You should make List<object> instead of List<string> as datasource. Object should contain fields with data to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in datasource, not reading. If you want to keep list of strings, use ListBox instead of Grid.

```
private void TypesByMonthRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    List<Source> typesByMonth = new List<String>();


    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["U04i5a"].ConnectionString;

    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        //string query = "SELECT DISTINCT type, COUNT(type) FROM appointment WHERE (start > @start && end < @end) GROUP BY type;";
        string query = "SELECT DISTINCT type FROM appointment;";

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                    {
                        typesByMonth.Add(new Source(reader["type"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ReportsDataGridView.DataSource = typesByMonth;

}
```

Comment: I used a text box to display the data and all is good now and all is good now. Thanks!